# Centered Wrapper Div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to center my webpage with

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    background: #fafafa;
    /*max-width: 1520px; */
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    text-align: left;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

From what I understand, the last two lines should center it, but the page is still glued to the left. All the content is inside the wrapper, and I've checked my HTML and CSS code with https://validator.w3.org so I don't think it can be incorrect tags.

Am I missing something?

Full code for the page is here: [HTML](https://github.com/vsfsdatateam/vsfsdatateam.github.io/blob/master/HTMLredo.html) [CSS](https://github.com/vsfsdatateam/vsfsdatateam.github.io/blob/master/CSSredo.css)

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: have you tried margin-left: auto; , margin-right: auto; ?

Comment: Yes, that doesn't seem to work either

Comment: fixed width + margin 0 auto should work. 
If it doesn't the problem is really somewhere else and not in the wrapper div. 
A bigger code sample or link to the working website would be needed to help you there.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/yemayip/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your .wrapper css with below one

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    background: #fafafa;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

> *Or another solution is set **`margin: auto;`** to body*

I hope this will help you

```css
/*
    DEMO STYLE
*/

@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";
body {
  font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
  background-image: url("path-to-stripe.png");
  max-width: 960px;
  /**background: #fafafa; **/
}

p {
  font-family: '{Poppins}',
  sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  color: #999;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 15px 40px;
  background: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar-btn {
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none !important;
  border: none;
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
  margin: 40px 0;
}


/*
div.wrapper{
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    max-width : auto ;
    position : center;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    background: #fafafa;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
*/


/* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  background: #fafafa;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#sidebar {
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 250px;
  background: #082e59;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 2.9);
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar.active {
  margin-left: -250px;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #082e59;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
  padding: 30px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
}

#sidebar ul p {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a:hover {
  color: #7386D5;
  background: #fff;
}

#sidebar ul li.active>a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
  color: #fff;
  background: #7192b7;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
  position: relative;
}

a[aria-expanded="false"]::before,
a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
  content: '\e259';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-size: 0.6em;
}

a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
  content: '\e260';
}

ul ul a {
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  padding-left: 30px !important;
  background: #082e59;
}

ul.CTAs {
  padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a.download {
  background: #fff;
  color: #7386D5;
}

a.article,
a.article:hover {
  background: #082e59 !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}


/* ---------------------------------------------------
    CONTENT STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

#content {
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}


/* ---------------------------------------------------
    MAP STYLES
----------------------------------------------------- */

#container1 {
  display: block;
  max-width: 1200px;
  min-height: 505px;
  position: auto;
  /* height: 475px; position: center;*/
  align-items: stretch;
}


/* ---------------------------------------------------
    MEDIAQUERIES
----------------------------------------------------- */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #sidebar {
    margin-left: -250px;
  }
  #sidebar.active {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  #sidebarCollapse span {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

  <title>NEA SCA Onboarding</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Our Custom CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>


  <div class="wrapper">
    <!-- Sidebar Holder -->
    <nav id="sidebar">
      <div class="sidebar-header">
        <p style="text-align:center;"><img src="stateheader.png" alt="div" width="100px" align="middle" /></p>
        <h3 style="text-align:center;">Onboarding</h3>
      </div>

      <ul class="list-unstyled components">
        <li class="active">
          <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="text-align:center;">Compare By</a>
          <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
            <li><a href="#">Population</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fertility Rate</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Health Expenses (%GDP)</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Military Expenses (%GDP)</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Education Expenses (%GDP)</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
          <a href="#index.html" style="text-align:center;">About This Tool</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="list-unstyled CTAs">
        <li><a href="https://bootstrapious.com/tutorial/files/sidebar.zip" class="download">View data source</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar" class="article">NEA/SCA Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <!-- Page Content Holder -->
    <div id="content">

      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">

          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn">
                                <i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i>
                            </button>
          </div>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
              <li><a href="#">Near East Asia (NEA)</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">South Central Asia (SCA)</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <h2>Near East Asia Region</h2>
        <p>This tool uses data from the CIA World Factbook to compare different countries in your region.</p>

        <!-- MAP CODE STARTS HERE -->
        <div id="container1">
          <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/topojson/1.6.9/topojson.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datamaps/0.5.8/datamaps.all.js"></script>

          <script>
            // example data from server
            var series = [
              ["DZA", 75],
              ["EGY", 43],
              ["IRN", 50],
              ["IRQ", 88],
              ["ISR", 21],
              ["JOR", 43],
              ["KWT", 21],
              ["LBN", 19],
              ["LBY", 60],
              ["MAR", 4],
              ["OMN", 44],
              ["QAT", 44],
              ["SAU", 44],
              ["SYR", 44],
              ["TUN", 44],
              ["ARE", 44],
              ["YEM", 38]
            ];


            // Datamaps expect data in format:
            // { "USA": { "fillColor": "#42a844", numberOfWhatever: 75},
            //   "FRA": { "fillColor": "#8dc386", numberOfWhatever: 43 } }
            var dataset = {};

            // We need to colorize every country based on "numberOfWhatever"
            // colors should be uniq for every value.
            // For this purpose we create palette(using min/max series-value)
            var onlyValues = series.map(function(obj) {
              return obj[1];
            });
            var minValue = Math.min.apply(null, onlyValues),
              maxValue = Math.max.apply(null, onlyValues);

            // create color palette function
            // color can be whatever you wish
            var paletteScale = d3.scale.linear()
              .domain([minValue, maxValue])
              .range(["#EFEFFF", "#02386F"]); // blue color

            // fill dataset in appropriate format
            series.forEach(function(item) { //
              // item example value ["USA", 70]
              var iso = item[0],
                value = item[1];
              dataset[iso] = {
                numberOfThings: value,
                fillColor: paletteScale(value)
              };
            });

            // render map
            var map = new Datamap({
              element: document.getElementById('container1'),
              projection: 'mercator', // big world map
              // countries don't listed in dataset will be painted with this color
              fills: {
                defaultFill: '#F5F5F5'
              },
              data: dataset,
              setProjection: function(element) {
                var projection = d3.geo.equirectangular()
                  .center([37.4, 25.7])
                  .rotate([4.4, 0])
                  .scale(450)
                  .translate([element.offsetWidth / 2, element.offsetHeight / 2]);
                var path = d3.geo.path()
                  .projection(projection);

                return {
                  path: path,
                  projection: projection
                };
              },
              geographyConfig: {
                borderColor: '#DEDEDE',
                highlightBorderWidth: 1,
                // don't change color on mouse hover
                highlightFillColor: function(geo) {
                  return geo['fillColor'] || '#F5F5F5';
                },
                // only change border
                highlightBorderColor: '#B7B7B7',
                // show desired information in tooltip
                popupTemplate: function(geo, data) {
                  // don't show tooltip if country don't present in dataset
                  if (!data) {
                    return;
                  }
                  // tooltip content
                  return ['<div class="hoverinfo">',
                    '<strong>', geo.properties.name, '</strong>',
                    '<br>Count: <strong>', data.numberOfThings, '</strong>',
                    '</div>'
                  ].join('');
                }
              }
            });

            map.legend();
          </script>
      </nav>
      </div>
      <!--MAP CODE ENDS HERE -->

    </div>
    <!--close content div-->
    <!--<p style="text-align:center;"><img src = "dos_divider.png" alt="div" align = "middle"/><p> -->
  </div>
  <!--close wrapper div> -->

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap Js CDN -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function() {
        $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
      });
    });
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want your content to be centered. Try this css change by adding margin: auto to the #content div:

```
#content {
padding: 20px;
min-height: 100vh;
transition: all 0.3s;
margin: auto;
```

}

Comment: I want the entire thing to  be centered, including the sidebar

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've set up a fixed max-width of 960px to the body element, which is preventing your wrapper to work. Remove it and it'll be fine.